# How to resize the height in Tabhost in android

Tags: android, tabs

I would like to resize the tabhost in android. I know it is deprecated, but this has been wonderful option for me because I am using ListActivity with custom cursor Adaptor. I am not if this posible with Fragment Tabhost.

Anyways to resize the tab height:

I tried the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) 
{
  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 80;
 }
```

It worked in few phones only. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: In which it didn't work?

Comment: Nexus 5... The same thing works fine in smaller resolution. How to fix this part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now, you are setting it in pixels, you should use dp,

try to replace

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 80;
```

with

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = (int) (80 * this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the tabwidget in the xml file.

```
<TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp">

        </TabWidget>
```

Change the height to whatever? That worked for me, if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: This also works, but then works only in few phones. Thanks Anyways!

Comment: Ah okay, I was unaware of that.